# How transform all values NOT = 0 in 1 with REGEX, efficiently

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've a Column that contains `0 and 12/02/19` dates, I want to transforming all dates into ones and multiply by the column `Enrolls_F`

-

Preferring using REGEX, but any other options should be fine too, it is a large Dataset, I tried with simple for loop and my kernel could not run it.

-

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Enrolled_Date': ['0','2019/02/04','0','0','2019/02/04','0'] , 'Enrolls_F': ['1.11','1.11','0.222','1.11','5.22','1']  })
```

Attempts:

trying to search for everything starts with `2` and replace with `1` and multiply by `Enrolls_F`

```
df_test =  (df.replace({'Enrolled_Date': r'2.$'}, {'Enrolled_Date': '1'}, regex=True)) * df.Enrolls_F

# Nothing happens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should help you get the trouble sorted;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Enrolled_Date': ['0','2019/02/04','0','0','2019/02/04','0'] , 'Enrolls_F': ['1.11','1.11','0.222','1.11','5.22','1']  }) 
df['Enrolled_Date'] = np.where(df['Enrolled_Date'] == '0',0,1)
df['multiplication_column'] = df['Enrolled_Date'] * df['Enrolls_F']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Enrolled_Date Enrolls_F multiplication_column
0              0      1.11
1              1      1.11                  1.11
2              0     0.222
3              0      1.11
4              1      5.22                  5.22
5              0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want output is float, try this

```
df.Enrolled_Date.ne('0').astype(int) * df.Enrolls_F.astype(float)

Out[212]:
0    0.00
1    1.11
2    0.00
3    0.00
4    5.22
5    0.00
dtype: float64
```